# Python: Two lists expression

Tags: python, list

I'm starting to learn Python. I'm studying it on some web course. There I saw strange expression in question to one of lections. There was comparing

```
0 < [1, 4][1] < 3
```

What do these two lists mean? And why

```
0 < [1, 4][1] - True
```

and

```
[1, 4][1] < 3 - False
```

There is no info about it in corresponding lection and my knowledge of Object Pascal and C# doesen't help.

Comment: There's only one list there. The `[1]` is indexing the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is combining the comparison operators and indexing into a list:

`[1, 4][1]` means the second member of the list (remember, the indexing starts at `0`, so it resolves to `4`. So it's the same as

```
0 < 4 < 3
```

which is `False` (because `0 < 4` is `False`. The logic is similar for the other two once you reduce them:

```
0 < 4 -> True
```

and

```
4 < 3 -> False
```

Comment: Thank you. I was guessing about it but need prove. As I see this is equivalent of @TimPietzcker variant. This explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

Look at it this way:

```
lst = [1, 4]
0 < lst[1] < 3   # lst[1] == 4
0 < 4            # True
4 < 3            # False
```